# Music and FX toggle in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

The question is very simple, I'm a beginner in unity and I'm having trouble creating two toggles for music and fx audio. At first I succeded with a simple script but the toggles encountered a NullReferenceException once the scene changed.

This is the AudioManager script:

```
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Toggle))]
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sound[] sounds;
    public static AudioManager instance;



    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        foreach (Sound s in sounds)
        {
            s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            s.source.clip = s.clip;
            s.source.volume = s.volume;
            s.source.pitch = s.pitch;
            s.source.loop = s.loop;
        }

    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Play("Music");
    }
    public void Play(string name)
    {

        Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);
        s.source.Play();
    }
}
```

do you have any suggestions about it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help folks more can you include the text of the error? It'll include the line number of the problem so please let folks know which line of your code it is. That'll make it easier for folks to help.

Answer (score 0):

What line is the NullReferenceException on? I don’t see anything wrong with your code as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Awake doesnt work for second time.

Because it is singleton.

So you can create OnEnable method, and put that foreach to OnEnable method.